# prevent reload after inline validation and ajax submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, form-submit

I am trying to prevent a reload after a ajax submission. 
The tricky part about it is that the form has to be validated before comes to the ajax submit.

So we click on the trigger, then "scrupulous.js" validates the form and then, if this is valid, we get our ajax submit. When I build in the "e.preventDefault();" the validation stop working also.

So my question: **How to prevent the default behavior without killing the validation?**

Thanks a lot!

```
$('.js_contact-form-submit').on('click', function (e) {

    var formObj = $(this).closest('form');

    $(formObj).scrupulous({
        valid: function () {

            var formData = {

                'gender': $('input[name=gender]:checked', formObj).val(),
                'firstName': $('input[name=firstname]', formObj).val(),
                'lastName': $('input[name=lastname]', formObj).val(),
                'message': $.trim($('input[name=message]', formObj).val())

            };

            var path = $(formObj).attr('data-component-path');

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: path + '.submitcontact',
                data: formData,
                success: function (data) {
                    // success block code
                    console.log('success' + data);
                },
                error: function (data) {

                    // failure block code
                    console.log('failure' + data);
                }

            });

        }

    });

    e.preventDefault();


});
```

Comment: Did you try having `return false;` after your `e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: @MilanChheda yes I did. It also kills the validation.

Comment: what causes the reload? something in scrupulous?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs no reload is caused by the submit. But with `e.preventDefault();` nothing works at all. I cant submit and the validation didn't work.

Comment: why not just change to `button type="button"`?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Just tried it. The validation is working again, but it doesn't prevent the default ajax behavior that reloads the page after submit.

Comment: ajax by default shouldn't reload.. it does whatever is in the success callback function, which is just a console.log - could you share full script please? :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs actually this is the full script. But thanx a lot for this hint! Maybe it is really a thing of [scrupulous.js](https://github.com/zaneray/scrupulous/blob/gh-pages/js/scrupulous.js)

Comment: @luckybusted could very well be - is it a .min script? if so, debugging will be hard xD

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs :D no it isn't! (thanks god) I posted the link in the comment before. And I think I already find something...

Comment: @luckybusted hahaha that is good good luck!